# How to find what is the Secondary private IPv4 addresses assoicated to an ec2 using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to find what is the "Secondary private IPv4 addresses" associated to an ec2 instance using AWS CLI? I have used below command but it displays all the IP's associated to it.

`aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the instance id, otherwise `aws ec2 describe-instances` will return the details of all the existing instances in your account for the particular region.

Try this:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <add the instance id> | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress'`

Comment: yes, I see it is printing both IP Addresses of specific instance ID. I need only "secondary private IPv4 address"